# Given two other percentiles values and median compute value percentile

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval

Let's assume I know the 90th and 10th percentile and the median of a given data set.

Is there a way to approximate what the, let's say, 30th percentile is with some statistical confidence?

Comment: Do you know anything about the shape of the distribution aside from what you can infer from those 3 values?

Comment: I do not. The data is hidden.

Comment: It could take any value between the 10th percentile and the 50th percentile (inclusive). Without any further information or assumptions you can't say any more than that. When you say that the data are hidden, is this for some class? An exam perhaps?

Comment: No this is for a personal problem I am trying to solve in the domain of web scrapin